# When doing Msbuild for x64 target cpu "An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format" error comes

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-assembly

I am trying to build my solution for 64 bit CPU. 
Initially i was facing following build issue

> An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll.

I was able to fix it using

```
<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>On</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
<SGenToolPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\</SGenToolPath>
```

Now i am facing the problem that

> An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format:
>   C:\MyFolder\MyProject\obj\release\myproj.dll.

I am unable to understand why this error is coming

Also i can see following warnings

> 1. Possible problem detected while building assembly myproj: Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor
> 2. Possible problem detected while building assembly myproj: Referenced assembly 'system.data.dll' targets a different processor
> 3. Possible problem detected while building assembly myproj: Referenced assembly 'system.web.dll' targets a different processor

Comment: For an answer with multiple upvotes this sure lacks a lot of information. Which version of VS/msbuild, how to reproduce, ... ?

Comment: @stijn Apologies for little imfomation Visual Studio 2012, windows 7 (64 bit). To reproduce: I had a project which was originally configured as target CPU 32-bit and worked fine. I changed the Target CPU to 64 bit. It started giving build error 1 i mentioned. Then after trying a workaround i am now facing the error 2.